# Pandas .loc[] returning another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the actual string variable instead another for text processing?

```
df.columns
df.head(3)
```

Returns

```
Index(['text', 'is_spam'], dtype='object')

779     Subject re a note being sent out under john s...    False
1552    Subject hi mind opt in referencement from h...  True
2341    Subject ilug do not drop your life insurance... True
```

Now trying to access the actual string I have:

```
string = df.loc[[i],['text']] # i is valid integer index
print(type(string))
```

Returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

How can I select the actual string variable? such that I can perform string operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string = df.loc[i, 'text']
```

Use code above instead of yours

Comment: omg! I did not know the effects of the double brackets.